# Querying nested navigation properties in odata

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I would like to expand all navigation properties in my odata service...

```
public class Order
{
     Product Product {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
     Category Category {get;set;}
}

public class Category
{
     string Name {get;set;}
}
```

How do I show all of these navigation properties? This is what I have

> /odata/Orders?$expand=Product

how do I also show the category??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
/odata/Orders?$expand=Product($expand=Category)
```

You can check with odata sample service:

http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(snopayoxlhy2hc4bpjgatvfj))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($expand=Photo)

Comment: I need to go one step further, any idea how I can do this? For example /odata/Orders?$expand=Product($expand=Category($expand=Something))

Comment: OData supports nested $expand. http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($expand=Friends($expand=Friends))

Comment: Is there a way to use $select for Product in this case? Looks like It only works for the top table (Orders) and the last expand (Category).

Comment: Absolutely, try ?$expand=Product($select=Description,Barcode;$expand=Category($select=CategoryName))

Comment: Im using OData V4 client code generator. How can I expand the `Category` using below expression? Context.Orders.ByKey(Id).Expand(x => x.Product);